# How to pass data between Application components

Tags: android

### My scenario

**1)** I know how to communicate between activites/service etc I am working on android 4+

**2)** I have a listview which generates  a list of all the songs(which is a fragment)

**3)** Now upon clicking upon any song,the whole list(mind it,the whole list and not just one song) is passed to a new activity.

**4)** This **new activity** launches a service again passing the whole list to a service to play the songs..

### The help that I need

Now i want to create some other dialogue/activity etc to show the now playing list,which can be edited by the user.My question is how should i do it ??i mean should i do it in an activity/dialogue/ or some other stuff,so that the interaction between these activities  and service remains very less?How can i efficiently reflect  changes happening in the now playing list to be reflected in the service as well as the **new activity** ?I am already creating so many copies of the same list so many times i just don't know how i can avoid making another copy ?

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer and you will get many subjective replies. What you should do is figure out some very specific questions to ask like: "Should I  use preferences instead of database for communicating between services" etc.

Comment: @cbrulak i don't mind subjective answers :)

Comment: But SO does. This is not really a discussion site, but a Q&A site and subjective questions are likely to be closed.

Comment: This would probably got a lot better over at reddit.com/r/androiddev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to create a [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for your song list. And work with [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Make static access to your **model** using events\controllers or directly from **Singleton**. If you need to pass same data over so many places it would be much better to store it in common place where everyone have access.

**Singletone** is a class that only constructed once in the application and everyone have access to it. It could be some thing like this:

```
public class MySingletone{
     private MySingletone(){}
     public static final MySingletone instance = new MySingletone();

     public MyModel getListModel(){
         // return your model here
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey i haven't worked with singleton .......... so i didn't get what you are trying to say,can you please explain a bit to me how singleton would work for me in this case? I am not asking for the code,just a little briefing

Comment: @user3144107 I think that the wiki article that I attached has a very good explanation, but I added few lines too.

Comment: whats exactly mymodel??is it a keyword?

Comment: @user3144107 It's part of MVC pattern, I suggest you to read about it too. In your case it's just your list. In my example I gave it a random type - MyModel

Comment: ok thanx wow this seems to be the answer to many of my questions,but if i have  a query later will you still reply?wait let me ask it right now,many times it happens that the activity is destroyed by the android system and hence so are the variables/objects defined inside the activity,what will happen in case of a singleton class ??will the information be lost ??(keep in mind that i will be using the same singleton class in the service as well)

Comment: Speak with me in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44245/ask-babibu). I will explain you why I prefer answering official questions. Also you can use @Babibu to notify me and I will see your message.